# Redsmin, cannot connect to redis instance

Tags: nosql, redis, redsmin

I am running a redis server instance as Windows server and can successfully connect to the instance from the command line cient to 127.0.0.1:6379. However I cannot connect to the very same instance through Redsmin. Can you please tell me exactly what the

- Server Name
- Redis Instance Type
- Redis Connection string

is supposed to be? My server instance is not password protected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **server name** is a logical name that will only be used to refer your server in Redsmin.

Since you got your own redis instance, you will want to add a "locally available" redis instance to Redsmin, [**see the docs**](https://redsmin.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/121169-can-i-manage-redis-instances-only-accessible-from-).

And since you are on windows, the installation should be something like this (**run these commands inside a powershell terminal**)

```
npm install redsmin -g
REDSMIN_KEY=YOUR_REDSMIN_CONNECTION_KEY redsmin
```

In this case your **Redis Connection string** will be used as a value for **RKEY**.

If you need anything else you can always contact us through our [uservoice](https://redsmin.uservoice.com/) page.

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate where those optional parameters go. Nowhere on your website could I find references to how to properly setup connectivity to a local instance through redsmin. And where would I type redsmin start? I still cannot connect to a simple local redis server instance in windows through  redsmin. Currently as it stands the service is completely unusable.

Comment: We have currently hundreds of users and a lot of them are running Redis through windows successfully so indeed there may be an issue with our documentation. Since you are one windows, just open a powershell terminal and run the specified commands. NodeJS as well as npm are required to do so as specified in the installation process. If you need more help just create a ticket from our uservoice page. We answer very quickly.

Comment: You will find your "YOUR_REDSMIN_CONNECTION_KEY" beside "Redsmin connection key" like in this screenshot: http://d.pr/i/TPOe

Comment: I got to connect to my Redis instance. But with all due respect your product is completely immature whether in beta or not, none of the functions work in the slightest. My gripes: a) cannot connect to my redis instance simply through the web service. If I can establish connectivity to a Redis instance with ip and port number then I should be able to do so through the web service rather than only be able to go through node.js. b) you lock people into having to maintain a subscription/account with you just to get access to the service. Not a great business model imho.

Comment: c) your monitoring service does not work at all, in fact it is all grayed out. Unusable!!! d) adding keys through the Redis console client is not reflected in your web client, no matter whether I refresh the webpage or not. Unusable!!! e) Adding keys through the web site does not work. Unusable!!! Changing configuration (clicking on Configuration hangs. Unusable!!!. Seriously, nothing works but you already have a big link on your website pointing to the fact you plan to introduce a paid subscription in the future? Wow. Great way to attract people. Sorry, not for me.

Comment: I still marked your answer as solving the question despite my frustration with RedsMin itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27421/discussion-between-fgribreau-and-freddy)

Comment: TL;DR: We have currently hundreds of users using Redsmin daily, the issues you are describing seem to be the consequence of a misconfiguration of your Redsmin-proxy.

Comment: This is exactly my gripe with Redsmin: A host address and port is not enough, given this is a local instance. Even running within NodeJS is not enough, it requires special configurations. See, this is not Redis itself that I would be fine with spending more time to setup but your application is one among many and if every other web monitoring tool works out of the box but yours does not then the choice becomes simple. What really put me off, however, was that you already look to monetize your work despite the app being not even in a stable Beta stage.

Comment: Fact remains that most of the functions you advertised do not work in the current version, your app says so itself, it is completely unrelated to any configurations or how do I understand the following messag "the whole monitoring feature is not working yet, but hey, we are still in Beta" (I paraphrased).

Comment: In the end I chose Redis-Commander a NodeJS app which works as advertised, free of charge, and was running straight out of the box. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Instead I ended up using the following commands from a normal command prompt (not powershell):

```
npm install redsmin@latest -g
set REDSMIN_KEY=[Proxy Connection Key]
redsmin
```

I was then able to connect from the Redsmin web app.

Comment: indeed, the answer was not updated since last Redsmin-proxy update, I fixed it. Thanks for reminding us of that!

Comment: Do not use quotes on Windows for `REDSMIN_KEY`